# How to store weather station Details along with monitoring data efficiently?

Tags: cassandra-2.0

I was following the TimeSeries data modelling in PlanetCassandra by Patrick McFadin.  Regarding that, I had one query:

If I need to store the weather station name also, should it be in the same table, say:

create table test (wea_id int, wea_name text, wea_add text, eventday timeuuid, eventtime timeuuid, temp int, PRIMARY KEY ((wea_id, eventday), eventtime) );

This forces me to enter the wea_name and wea_add for each new row, so how to identify a new row has been created?  Or is there any better mechanism for modeling the above data?

Regards,
Seenu.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're referring to the article on getting started with time series data modeling at http://planetcassandra.org/getting-started-with-time-series-data-modeling/

The original CQL listed is:

```
CREATE TABLE temperature_by_day (
weatherstation_id text,
date text,
event_time timestamp,
temperature text,
PRIMARY KEY ((weatherstation_id,date),event_time)
);
```

If you need to add an attribute that's associated with the partition key, in this case (weatherstation_id,date), Cassandra has a feature that does just that:  static columns
http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/refStaticCol.html

So you could write the statment as this:

```
CREATE TABLE temperature_by_day (
weatherstation_id text,
weatherstation_name text STATIC,
date text,
event_time timestamp,
temperature text,
PRIMARY KEY ((weatherstation_id,date),event_time)
);
```

You would be storing the name once per (weatherstation_id,date) combination rather than for every observation.

Ideally you'd like to store a name once per weather station.  Using this choice of partition key you can't do this;  you could model with one device per partition as per Patrick's first example if you like:

```
CREATE TABLE temperature (
weatherstation_id text,
weatherstation_name text STATIC,
event_time timestamp,
temperature text,
PRIMARY KEY ((weatherstation_id),event_time)
);
```

Comment: I agree that storing a name once with weather station would be enough, but it not suitable for storing time series (as the no. of rows would increase but the above example would limit only one row per day).
To certain extent STATIC will help, in the sense that I can have it only once per partition.